# CDI Dynamic Bean Instances

Tags: java, cdi, wildfly, java-ee-7, weld

Working with Wildfly / JBoss Weld / CDI 1.1.

Lets say you have a database. Can be anything, MySQL, MongoDB. Could be a REST service. From that database, you get a list of Animals.

```
[
  "Cat",
  "Dog",
  "Giraffe",
  "Tiger",
  "Chicken"
]
```

You do not know what animals you will get from this service, but what you want to do is make them available for Instance injection.

Animal Class:

```
public class Animal {
  private final String type;
  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }
  public Animal(String aType) {
    type = aType;
  }
}
```

Injection Point:

```
@Inject @Any
public Instance<Animal> animals;
```

You can make a Producer method that makes AN animal, for instance with a qualifier to make a certain animal:

```
@Produces @AnimalType
public Animal makeAnimal(InjectionPoint ip) {
  // Get AnimalType qualifier and make a new Animal(typeString), 
  // ...
  return animal;
}
```

But how do you Produce ALL (known from data) animals so that you can iterate over them with instance?

```
for(Animal animal : animals) {
  // ...
}
```

I do want each Animal to get the benefits of Dependency Injection and other Weld/CDI goodies.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be looking for [Unmanaged](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.1/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/Unmanaged.html)

```
Unmanaged<Animal> unmanagedAnimal = new Unmanaged<>(Animal.class);
UnmanagedInstance<Animal> animalInstance = unmanagedAnimal.newInstance();
Animal animal = animalInstance.produce().inject().postConstruct().get();
```

Its basically a dependent scoped bean, but you need to manually destroy it when done.

Comment: Unmanaged it used to transform non bean class in an injection target. Here the need is to be able to inject animal anywhere. Unmanaged is not enough for that. The only solution is to make these animals beans...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the InjectionPoint concept, you can not use it with Instance in that way. Instance and InjectionPoint with producer-method is used to inject the

```
 Instance<Animal>
```

into the producer-method with all CDI-animals and the let the producer-method decide, which animal to return, depending on the InjectionPoint:

```
 public Animal make(@Any Instance<Animal> instance, InjectionPoint ip)
```

See also here https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/java-ee-cdi-programmatic-dependency-disambiguation-example-injection-point-inspection.html

Or to produce a configured Object, depending on Qualifier-Config-Inputs like here https://dzone.com/articles/cdi-di-p2

In your case you must tell CDI, how to find the producer-methods:

```
  @Qualifier
  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  @Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
  public @interface AnimalType {
      String value();   
  }
```

Then you can write the appropriate producer methods:

```
@Produces
@AnimalType("Monkey")
public Animal makeAnimalApe() {
    return new Animal("Cheetah");
}


@Produces
@AnimalType("Mouse")
public Animal makeAnimalMouse() {
    return new Animal("Jerry");
}

@Produces
@AnimalType("Cat")
public Animal makeAnimalCat() {
    return new Animal("Tom");
}
```

And then you can inject it:

```
@Inject
@Any
private Instance<Animal> anyAnimal;

@Inject
@AnimalType("Monkey")
private Animal monkey;

@PostConstruct
public void create(){
    System.out.println(monkey.name);
    anyAnimal.forEach((a)->System.out.println(a.name));
}
```

But in this case you have to write a producer-method for each selection-case. I fear, that's not suitable.

To use the InjectionPoint, you can make the AnimalType NOT a Qualifier

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface AnimalType {
    String value(); 
}
```

Now you must use the InjectionPoint:

```
@Produces
public Animal makeAnimalApe(InjectionPoint p) {
    AnimalType t = p.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(AnimalType.class);
    if (t != null) {
        String s = t.value();
        if ("Monkey".equals(s))
            return new Animal("Cheetah");
        else if ("Mouse".equals(s))
            return new Animal("Jerry");
        else if ("Cat".equals(s))
            return new Animal("Tom");
    }       
    throw new EJBException("Please annotate the animal injection point with AnimalType");
}
```

But you cannot inject Instance into your bean because lack of the Qualifier AnimalType. So you have to produce a simple List like this:

```
@Produces
public List<Animal> produceAll(){
    List<Animal> all = new ArrayList<>();
    all.add(new Animal("Cheetah"));
    all.add(new Animal("Jerry"));
    all.add(new Animal("Tom"));
    return all;
}
```

So you can inject just one or all

```
@Inject
@AnimalType("Monkey")
private Animal monkey;
@Inject
private List<Animal> all;
```